# What is the Recommended Default Lock Screen Background Size

Tags: windows-phone-8

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968(v=vs.105).aspx a default lock screen image should be placed in the root of the project with a specific name. Is there a recommended size? I know for splashscreens if you only want to use one for all device sizes it should be 768x1280. Would this be similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Nokia Developer resources for WP8, the recommended Lock Screen background size is etiher 480px x 800px or 960px x 1708px. Additionally, they go on to mention that if a larger image is provided it will be cropped from the center and set in lock screen, if the image is smaller, it iwll be stretched to fit the screen.

Comment: Would be good to add a link to the Nokia Developer page if possible.

Comment: I would have thought that the lock screen images would be 480x800, 768x1280 or 720x1280. Although I see a couple of user-created articles that mention "960x1708" (http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8), I cannot find any definitive reference that says so.